# How to start next asynchronous task with Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, settimeout

In some cases we need to start asynchronous task like:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    // do something

}, 0);
```

It starts asynchronous task for content.

But it is ugly and not recommended.
How could I do that with `Observable`?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) rather than Observable. It's native and you can acheive the same things with it :

```
let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // we do something

  if(/* an error has occured */) {
      // we don't want to return in the then function if there is an error.
      reject(theError);
  }
  let valueToReturn = "we want to return this from the promise";
  resolve(valueToReturn);
});

myPromise.then((data) => {
    //the async process is done
    console.log(data) // <-- "we want to return this from the promise"
}).catch((error) => {
   // we print the error if there is one.
   console.error(error);
});
```

Sure, you can use some wonderful function with Observable, such as `pipe`, but if you don't need it, you don't need an whole new library just for that.

Comment: With promises it can be simplified to Promise.resolve(true).than(... But I'm working with Angular and would prefer not to mix Observables with Promises,

Comment: Having `Promise.resolve(true).then(...)` does not achieve anythings. Your promise is resolve instantly. If you want to use Observable, you can use `new Observable(subscriber => { // do somehting }).subscribe(...)` [source](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable)

Comment: Promise.resolve(true).then(...) starts new Microtask. Indeed it differs from setTimeout (that starts Mackotask), but in many cases it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario (`setTimeout, 0`) you can  use [Schedulers](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/scheduler). Internally the `asyncScheduler` works with an `setInterval`.

```
source$.pipe(
  observeOn(asyncScheduler)
);
```